# Unsure on how to resolve the timeout exception error while using selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I want to scrape data from a video game stat website and click on each win I have and collect my stats from that match. here is the code I have so far:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    url = "https://destinytracker.com/destiny-2/profile/psn/4611686018440125811/matches?mode=crucible"
    driver.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    crucible_content = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.trn-gamereport-list.trn-gamereport-list--compact")))
    game_reports = crucible_content.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "trn-gamereport-list__group")
    for game_report in game_reports:
        group_entry = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "trn-gamereport-list__group-entries")))
        win_match = group_entry.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"trn-match-row--outcome-win")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", win_match[0])
        lose_match = group_entry.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "trn-match-row--outcome-loss")
        for win_element in win_match:
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", win_element)

            win_left = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "trn-match-row__section--left")))
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", win_left)
           
            date_time = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='info']")))
            date_time = date_time.text
            date_time = date_time.split(",")
            date_time = date_time[0]
            print(date_time)
```

I want to loop over each win and click on it so that I can access the pcgr variable and do more digging from there, however, I always get a timeout exception when I get there and I'm not sure what's been causing it, I've increased the wait time from 20 to 30 seconds and even asked chatGPT for help but to no avail. It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could help. What's weird is that I'm able to print date_time even though its further down the line.

Comment: At which line are you geting TimeoutException?

Comment: the pcgr line. @undetectedSelenium

Comment: You aren't using `drawer_container` and `pcgr` anywhere later in your code, why notremoving the lines?

Comment: my apologies, im not quite sure what you mean @undetectedSelenium

Comment: i removed the drawer_container and pcgr code lines but it still shows the timeout error for date_time when I tried  to call it using wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located). which is odd since it printed out the date_time